# Problems with VBA and Charts

Tags: vba, charts

```
    Sub AddChart()
Dim ch As ChartObject
Set ch = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(200, 200, 200, 200)
Dim chData As Range
Set chData = Range("B2:B13")
Dim chTitle As Range
Set chTitle = Range("C1")

With ch.Chart
.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("2_Basisdata").Range("B1:B13")
.Charttype = xlColumnClustered
.HasTitle = True
.Charttitle = "chTitle"
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Monate"
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Werte"

End With
End Sub
```

New Problem that has to be solved :D
I have to pick out of my Basisdata worksheet a Special Row and then create a Chart with it.

Error is Runtime 438
Object doesnt support the property or method
holdmarker is at charttitle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the Chart object's [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff196832.aspx), I see that you need to use its `Text` property:

`.Charttitle.Text = "chTitle"`

Comment: thats solves the runtime error but im not able to get the value/string whats saved for the variable into the chart :/